# Как вывести данные с таблицы MySQL через запятую?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть у мене база данных Mysql, название ее "db_edmpeople" в ней есть таблица "news" в этой таблицы "teg" (тип: text, значение: "Tiesto, RadioShow") - как выводить данные через запятую следующим образом?

```
<p class="teg">Теги: 
<a href="#" class="teg2">Tiesto</a>, 
<a href="#" class="teg2">RadioShow</a></p>
```

у меня есть такой код

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE visible='1'",$link);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{

 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 do {

    echo '    
        <div class="item-news">
        <a href="open_news.html" class="title">'.$row["title"].'</a>
        <div class="date">'.$row["datetime"].'   ,  просмотров: '.$row["count"].' , <a href="#" class="date2">2 Отзыва </a></div>
        <img class="images" width="400" height="400" src="'.$row["image"].'" alt="'.$row["title"].'">

        <p class="text" height="20px">'.$row["mini_description"].' <a href="#" class="text4">Читать</a></p>

        <p class="teg">Теги: <a href="#" class="teg2">'.$value.'</a>,

        <p class="line"></p>
</div>

    ';

 }

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)); {

 }

}

 ?>
```

Comment: Вам бы базу отнормализовать (хранить теги в отдельной таблице со связью многие-к-одному), а не то, что вы хотите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$tagsExplode = explode(", ", $result->teg);
echo '<p class="teg">Теги:';
forech($tagsExplode as $tag => $value) {
  echo '<a href="#" class="teg2">' . $value . '</a>';
}
echo '</p>';
```

А вообще люди правильно советуют, сделай правильную структуру БД, и запроси многие к одному
[StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217742/one-to-many-mysql)

Comment: что-то не работает..

Comment: @Titan93, напишите, в чем провяляется неработоспособность.

Comment: @Titan93, там опечатка, `forech` -> `foreach`

Comment: @Titan93, мы ничего не можем сказать по "не работает". По "ошибка: *текст ошибки*" - можем. А так не можем.

Comment: У человека объектно-ориентированным подходом не пахнет, а он наверно скопипастил строку $tagsExplode = explode(", ", $result->teg);
 "как есть"))
@Titan93, попробуйте изменить её на:

    $tagsExplode = explode(", ", $result['teg']); // хотя правильно пишется "tag"

Comment: почему вместо данные с базы выводится, Array (типа пустой массив)
P.S. насчет этого "teg" у меня опечатка была, в базе данных у таблице "tag"

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE visible='1'",$link);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 do {

 $tagsExplode = explode(",", $row['tag']);
 
 echo '<div class="item-news">
        
   <p class="teg">Теги: <a href="#" class="teg2">'.$tagsExplode.'</a>
   
   <p class="line"></p>
</div>'; 
  
 

 }


 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)); {
 
 }

}

Comment: @Titan93, в мире столько хороших профессий, а вы драгоценное время тратите. ![alt text][1]

    // эту функцию куданибудь за пределы цикла
    function parseTags($t){
      return '<span>'.implode('</span>,<span>', explode(", ", $t)).'</span>';
    }
    // а в цикле:
    echo '<p class="teg">Теги: '.parseTags($row['tags']).'</a>';



  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/iZ7fP9z.gif

Comment: работает но только все под одной ссылкой ?

Comment: @Titan93,  Значит измените функцию, делайте через цикл, как показал @Quiss и оборачивайте каждый тег в ссылку.

Comment: >работает но только все под одной ссылкой ?

Ну так хоть чуть-чуть проявите творческий подход! Это даже не творчество, а одноразовое find/replace:

    return '<a href="#" class="tag2">'.implode('</a>,<a href="#" class="tag2">', explode(',', $t)).'</a>';

Comment: спасибо, но один тег выводит пустым (перший тег пустой)